# Waiting for a process to start

Tags: c#, console

When the console starts, it will send a message "Waiting for process" and when you run the program, send a message to the console again "The process started"

While it works but I feel like the code is dirty, is there no other way to do it? Regards.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting notepad.exe ---------------");

    Thread th = new Thread(testProcess);
    th.Start();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void testProcess()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (processes.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `Thread.Sleep(0)` inside the `while`.

Comment: @Sinatr why? 
What is the idea?

Comment: I was hoping to find a good post to link, but couldn't find a good one talking about *tight loops*. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17376601/1997232) is explanation though.

Comment: For codereview consider to use [dedicated site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).